# Как перенести функцию из одного файла в другой если в функции используются переменные из другого файла?

Tags: python, tkinter, файловая-система

К примеру. У меня есть файл *test.py* с данным кодом.

```
from test1 import Func
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

ent = Entry()
but = Button(text='YES', command=Func())


ent.grid()
but.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

И второй файл с функцией - *test1.py*

```
def Func():
    text = ent.get()
    print(text)
```

при запуске программы выводит ошибка, что переменной ent в файле *test1.py* не существует. При попытке передать переменную *ent* из файла *test.py* в файл *test1.py* в качестве аргумента то он сразу запускает функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб можно было передать параметр, но при этом не вызывать функцию можно сделать связывание параметра:

```
# test.py
from functools import partial

but = Button(text='YES', command=partial(Func, ent))


# test1.py

def Func(ent):
    text = ent.get()
    print(text)
```

Конструкция `partial(Func, ent)` создает новую функцию, которая уже не содержит параметров, а при вызове запустит `Func(ent)`, т.е. приблизительно такую:

```
def tempFunc():
    return Func(ent)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто! Похоже ты создаешь функцию в новом файле. Зачем? Ты можешь оставить функцию в основном файле и использовать её во втором благодаря import.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но просто мой код больше чем этот. Его я написал в качестве примера. Я хотел бы разделить функции для кнопок и сам интерфейс, чтобы было более удобно ориентироваться в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Может поздновато, но может кто то столкнулся с такой же проблемой.
покажу на своем примере.
у меня есть

```
папка_1
  папка_2
    папка_с_файлом_1
      файл_с_кодом
    папка_с_файлом_2
      файл_с_классом
```

файл_с_классом

```
from tkinter import *
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

файл_с_кодом

```
from папка_1.папка_2.папка_с_файлом_2.файл_с_классом import Window
handle = Window()

handle.title('Daw')
handle.geometry('1280x720')

handle.mainloop()
```

Как видно на примере, нужно написать полный путь через `.`
То есть написать

```
from папка_2.папка_с_файлом_2.файл_с_классом import Window
```

не достаточно! Нужно написать полный путь от проекта:

```
from папка_1.папка_2.папка_с_файлом_2.файл_с_классом import Window
```